# How to make gVIM portable

Tags: windows, portable, gvim

Is it possible to make a default **gVIM** installation (**Windows**) portable so that I can carry it on a USB stick?

I know there are a few portable distributions out there, but they all seem to be unmaintained.

Comment: Since you are not mentioning what platform you are on, I assume it is some incarncation of Windows?

Comment: Edited question to add platform (Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gVim Portable](http://portableapps.com/node/15654)  is a feature rich and not-too-hard-to-use text editor, and a very feature rich one at that. With gVim you can code, highlight syntax, and do everything else you would expect of a text editor worth its weight in megabytes.

Comment: i liked gvim portable. but i hated the fact that you can't rename the .exe file.

Comment: ya .its true ;)

Answer (score 2):

gVim is pretty much portable as is. If you download the binaries from vim.org, from the zip file (or .tz, I'm not sure now). and start using it you'll notice the only thing it leaves is your backup and swap and similar files in ... documents and settings ... directory.

Put this in your vimrc

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set viminfo=
```

and, if I'm not mistaken, it should work like a charm.

Comment: "gVim is pretty much portable as is" .. well, thats pretty much true for all software :)

Comment: ?? ... what I ment was that gvim is portable even in its non-portable binaries distribution, if you take the above into consideration. That is hardly true for most software. ... what did you mean ?

Comment: i meant that you can actually move around the folders in %PROGRAMFILES% (or their equivalent in other OS) pretty freely. i am doing this even with visual studio, the 'only' thing to do is setting some enviromnet variables... thats the normal way of deploying software: "copy it into a folder". that fact is nothing special for vim, thats all i was trying to say... dont take it too seriously.

Comment: no, no ... non taken :)

But I don't understand ... you're saying one can for example, rename a folder in program files and move it somewhere else or ... I din't quite catch your meaning ...

please, do explain.

Comment: exactly, take a folder, rename it and most software will work. thats the reason why portableapps.com can take the software and 'repack' it.

Answer (score 1):

To make gvim portable you need only change the HOME directory. It does not take more than a small batch script to accomplish this.

Suppose you have already downloaded the gvim archive as well as its runtime files and installed them. Your gvim installation is something like this:

```
C:\path\to\your\vim\vim81\gvim.exe
```

where 81 is the version number which may change accordingly.

Create a `home` directory just parallel to the folder containing `gvim.exe`, and a batch file (named `portable_gvim.bat`, say) right into the `gvim.exe` folder, like this:

```
vim
├─home
│      _viminfo
│      _vimrc
│      
└─vim81
    │  gvim.exe
    │  portable_gvim.bat
    │  
    ├─autoload
    ............
```

then enter the contents of `portable_gvim.bat` as following:

```
:: Changing gvim's home directory to make it portable
:: Put this file next to gvim.exe 

@echo off
setlocal

pushd %~dp0..
set "HOME=%CD%\home"
popd

start "" "%~dp0gvim.exe" %*

endlocal
echo on
```

and that's it. put your _vimrc in that portable home, launch the batch, and enjoy.